# How to get application scope variable in jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

I've intialized a variable in `ServletContext` listener using the following code:

```
sce.getServletContext().setAttribute("foo", "someValue");
```

So, I can now get the value using following code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("foo");
```

Now, I want to access this value in some other class that is not a `FacesContext`, or is not a controller. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other class is not running in `FacesContext` or `ServletContext`, then you simply can't.

Just pass it as constructor or method argument.

```
otherClass.doSomething(foo);
```