# Managed property inheritance

Tags: jsf, inheritance, jsf-2

My problem is similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901219/viewscope-constructor-called-twice-not-sure-why). I have a **BaseBean** which currently has just a single property which is annotated as a `@ManagedProperty`.

However, when I access the getter of this *inherited* managed property in the action method a commandbutton, it returns null. I debugged and confirmed that the base bean constructr was called twice - once on page load and next on click of the button as already described in the mentioned link.

I followed the suggestions as mentioned the article's chosen answer as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214146/calling-postconstruct-on-super-bean-and-extending-bean) post, but to no avail.

Following is my code:

```
public abstract class BaseBean
{
   @ManagedProperty(value = "#{serviceLocator}")
   private IServiceLocator serviceLocator;

   public IServiceLocator getServiceLocator() {
      return serviceLocator;
   }

   public void setServiceLocator(IServiceLocator serviceLocator) {
      this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
   }
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RegistrationBean extends BaseBean implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -6449858513581500971L;

   private String userID;
   private String password;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email;
   private String addressLine1;
   private String addressLine2;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private String pincode;

   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationBean.class);

   /* getter / setters */

   public String register() 
   {
      String nextPage = null;
      try {
         RegistrationDetails userDetails = ModelBuilder.populateRegistrationData(this);
         int registrationID = getServiceLocator().getUserService().registerUser(userDetails);
         LOGGER.info("Registered user successfully. Registration ID - {}", registrationID);
         nextPage = "success";
      }
      catch (RegistrationException e) {
         LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
      }
      return nextPage;
   }

   public void checkUserExists() 
   {
      int regID = getServiceLocator().getUserService().findUser(getUserID());

      if(regID > 0) {
         FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "User already exists !!", null);
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
      }
   }
}
```

Why would the constructor be called again on form submit ??? :/

The getter returns null even in the `checkUserExists()` method which is called via ajax on the blur event of the userID field.

**EDIT** : Added code for ServiceLocator..

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceLocator implements IServiceLocator
{
   private static final String USER_SERVICE = "userService";
   private static final String MOVIE_SERVICE = "movieService";

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
      final ServletContext sc = FacesUtils.getServletContext();
      this.webAppContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc);
      this.userService = (IUserService) webAppContext.getBean(USER_SERVICE);
      this.movieService = (IMovieService) webAppContext.getBean(MOVIE_SERVICE);
   }

   private ApplicationContext webAppContext;

   private IUserService userService;

   private IMovieService movieService;

   @Override
   public IUserService getUserService() {
      return userService;
   }

   @Override
   public IMovieService getMovieService() {
      return movieService;
   }
}
```

Comment: what about the `register` its returning string , which cause the view bean to be recreated...

Comment: @Daniel : The NPE occurs before it can reach the return statement. `getServiceLocator()` returns null... :|

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46792693/1599699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you're trying to mix two answers: one for `@RequestScoped` mbeans and other for `@ViewScoped` mbeans. If you see the first link you've posted, BalusC is saying that you don't have to have `@ManagedProperty` in `@ViewScoped` mbeans as shown in [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = “#{param.id})”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4888942/1065197).

If you can't pass the `serviceLocator` through a view param, you have to find another way to get that value (saving/retrieving it from session).

Also, check this info from BalusC explaining why the `@ViewScoped` mbean could be recreated on every request:

> In a nutshell: the @ViewScoped breaks when any UIComponent is bound to the bean using binding attribute or when using JSTL  or  tags in the view. In both cases the bean will behave like a request scoped one. The first one is in my opinion a pretty major bug, the second one is only an extra excuse to get rid of the whole JSTL stuff in Facelets.
>
> This is related to JSF 2.0 issue 1492. Here's an extract of relevance:
>   This is a chicken/egg issue with partial state saving. The view is executed to populate the view *before* delta state is applied, so we see the behavior you've described.
>   At this point, I don't see a clear way to resolve this use case.
>   The workaround, if you must use view-scoped bindings would be setting javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to false.

From

- [The benefits and pitfalls of @ViewScoped](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html)

---

Based on your comment and edit, you can access to the `@ApplicationScoped` mbean by using the code provided here:

- [How to get application scope variable in jsf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4862860/1065197)

This would be the line:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getApplicationMap().get("serviceLocator");
```

You have to use that code since, apparently, the `@ViewScoped` bean can't accept injection by `@ManagedProperty`.

Comment: ServiceLocator is an application scoped bean which is just delegating calls to the services. I posted the ServiceLocator code in my question. Thanks, for pointing out my confusion.. :)

Comment: That seemed to work :D. I wasn't using this method since I assume it would be available via the injection. So, does this have to do something to Viewscope ???

Comment: @VrushankDesai Apparently yes, it looks like you can't inject beans/values in `@ViewScoped` managed beans other way than using `<f:viewparam>`. It's very strange (even for me), but we have to use the technology the way it is atm =\. At least, you managed to solve your problem =). Don't forget to mark this post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code for `ServiceLocator` isn't shown, so there's a number of open questions that may help identify an answer to your issue.  I'll comment or ask a question, and perhaps something will trigger an "Aha!" for you:

- Verify that `ServiceLocator` is in fact annotated with `@ManagedBean`.
- Remember that you can't inject a bean with a shorter scope (life span) than the target bean.  In this case, if `ServiceLocator` is, say, `@RequestScoped`, then it cannot be injected into your `@ViewScoped` bean.
- are we to presume that `IServiceLocator` is an interface implemented by some managed bean `ServiceLocator`?
- `ServiceLocator` smells like an EJB; if it is, use `@EJB` to inject an EJB.

Comment: Yes, no it isn't, yes and no. Updated my question with the code of service locator class.. :)