# ApplicationScoped Bean is null on rich:tab's actionListener-method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm using JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 3.3.2.
I'm having an issue on one of my pages.

First of all I have a main page which contains a rich:tabPanel with several rich:tabs, no problem there switching between them.

On the first tab of my page I have another tabPanel with some other tabs. 
They all have an actionListener which will call the ViewScoped ManagedBean to edit some Data, which will be displayed on the clicked tab. The method to edit the data calls a method on an ApplicationScoped Bean which is correctly injected (It works in other tabs). When switching a tab on the second layer and the action-method is called, the ApplicationScoped Bean is null.
This only happens when I switch tabs (so it does not happen on the first tab, which is displayed by default) so I think it's related to the actionListener, but i can't figure out why. Unfortunately I can't provide the actual code but this is the rough structure of my page.

mainPage.xhtml

```
...
<rich:tabPanel>
    <rich:tab>
        <ui:include src="tabs/tab1.xhtml" />
    </rich:tab>
    otherTabs
</rich:tabPanel>
...
```

tab1.xhtml

```
...
<rich:tabPanel>
    <rich:tab actionListener="#{viewScopedBean.method}">
        <ui:include src="subtabs/subtab1.xhtml" /> 
    </rich:tab>
    <rich:tab actionListener="#{viewScopedBean.method2}">
        <ui:include src="subtabs/subtab2.xhtml" /> 
    </rich:tab>
</rich:tabPanel>
```

ViewScopedBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopedBean {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{applicationBean}")
    private ApplicationBean applicationBean;

    private Data data;

    public void init() {
        ...
        data = applicationBean.retrieveData();
        ...
    }

    public void method(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        data = applicationBean.retrieveData();
        ...
    }

    public void method2(ActionEvent e) {
        ...
        data = applicationBean.retrieveData();
        ...
    }
    // getters/setters
}
```

ApplicationBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class applicationBean {
     public Data retrieveData() {
           ...
     }
 }
```

When clicking subtab2 I get a NullPointerException at the line data = applicationBean.getData(), so the applicationBean is null. This happens everytime on every tab I'm switching to, but never in the init() method, so the applicationBean should not be null.
I could not find any solution or hints on this problem and hope someone has an idea.

Thanks in advance
regards

Comment: What are you doing within those `ActionListener`s? Can you verify that the `@ViewScoped` is working as expected, i.e. it's not re-instantiated mid-request?

Comment: Maybe my answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13221012/1065197) (check the bottom part) could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Your posted question led me to this. http://balusc.blogspot.de/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html 
the line "Note that the bean needs to implement Serializable as it will be stored in the view map which is in turn stored in the session." solved my problem. Thank you